# Pattern not found with Omnisharp, VIM and csharp

Tags: c#, vim, omnisharp

I'm been trying to set up omnisharp to work with csharp projects with Vim. Here is my setup

Here is my setup

```
lsb_release -a
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty
```

I'm actually using crouton, on a chromebook. I use `sudo enter-chroot` and use Vim that way.

My VIM info

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Jan  2 2014 19:39:32)
Included patches: 1-52
Modified by pkg-vim-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org
Compiled by buildd@
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl             +farsi           +mouse_netterm   +syntax
+arabic          +file_in_path    +mouse_sgr       +tag_binary
+autocmd         +find_in_path    -mouse_sysmouse  +tag_old_static
-balloon_eval    +float           +mouse_urxvt     -tag_any_white
-browse          +folding         +mouse_xterm     -tcl
++builtin_terms  -footer          +multi_byte      +terminfo
+byte_offset     +fork()          +multi_lang      +termresponse
+cindent         +gettext         -mzscheme        +textobjects
-clientserver    -hangul_input    +netbeans_intg   +title
-clipboard       +iconv           +path_extra      -toolbar
+cmdline_compl   +insert_expand   -perl            +user_commands
+cmdline_hist    +jumplist        +persistent_undo +vertsplit
+cmdline_info    +keymap          +postscript      +virtualedit
+comments        +langmap         +printer         +visual
+conceal         +libcall         +profile         +visualextra
+cryptv          +linebreak       +python          +viminfo
+cscope          +lispindent      -python3         +vreplace
+cursorbind      +listcmds        +quickfix        +wildignore
+cursorshape     +localmap        +reltime         +wildmenu
+dialog_con      -lua             +rightleft       +windows
+diff            +menu            -ruby            +writebackup
+digraphs        +mksession       +scrollbind      -X11
-dnd             +modify_fname    +signs           -xfontset
-ebcdic          +mouse           +smartindent     -xim
+emacs_tags      -mouseshape      -sniff           -xsmp
+eval            +mouse_dec       +startuptime     -xterm_clipboard
+ex_extra        +mouse_gpm       +statusline      -xterm_save
+extra_search    -mouse_jsbterm   -sun_workshop    -xpm
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/share/vim"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H     -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1      
Linking: gcc   -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,--as-needed -o vim        -lm -ltinfo -lnsl  -lselinux  -lacl -lattr -lgpm -ldl    -L/usr/lib/python2.7/config-x86_64-linux-gnu -lpython2.7 -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lm -Xlinker -export-dynamic -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions
```

my .vimrc file for testing

```
execute pathogen#infect()
syntax on
filetype plugin indent on

set statusline+=%#warningmsg#
set statusline+=%{SyntasticStatuslineFlag()}
set statusline+=%*

let g:syntastic_always_populate_loc_list = 1
let g:syntastic_auto_loc_list = 1
let g:syntastic_check_on_open = 1
let g:syntastic_check_on_wq = 0
```

My plugins. I'm using pathogen

```
YouCompleteMe  omnisharp-vim  syntastic  vim-dispatch
```

My mono version

```
Mono JIT compiler version 4.0.2 (Stable 4.0.2.5/c99aa0c Wed Jun 24 10:04:37 UTC 2015)
Copyright (C) 2002-2014 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
        TLS:           __thread
        SIGSEGV:       altstack
        Notifications: epoll
        Architecture:  amd64
        Disabled:      none
        Misc:          softdebug 
        LLVM:          supported, not enabled.
        GC:            sgen
```

When I open a cs file from a project, I get the following message, so the server is being launched

```
!mono '/home/bilal/.vim/bundle/omnisharp-vim/server/OmniSharp/bin/Debug/OmniSharp.exe' -p 2000 -s '/home/bilal/Documents/deletethis/test1/test1.sln'
 (headless/24015)
```

But I always get the following message everytime instead of any intellisense

```
Omni completion (^O^N^P) Pattern not found
```

I tried using C-x, C-o, but I always get the same message.

Is there anything I can do to debug this some more? Not really sure what I'm doing wrong here

Thanks

Comment: Same thing happening to me. Did you find a solution since then?

Comment: i did not unfortunately. I gave up on this a while back.

Answer (score 1):

This was happening to me, I had missed out the step of running `xbuild` from within the server folder.

Re-running the last two lines below fixed it for me.

```
cd ~/.vim/bundle
git clone https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vim.git
cd omnisharp-vim
git submodule update --init --recursive
cd server
xbuild
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I finally got a chance to try this out again, and it still didn't work. I don't know if this is a issue with vim or crouton. sigh..